# Execute function only for specific user roles

Tags: php, functions, user-roles

I'm referencing the below  solution (which came from here [Force Password Complexity](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149413/enforcing-password-complexity))  to enforce a certain level of password security. It works as expected, but it is running for ALL user roles. I do not want to enforce the same parameters to the basic 'subscriber' role. How do I block the code from running for certain roles? (Or, force it to run for certain roles such as Administrator, Editor, etc.)

```
add_action('user_profile_update_errors', 'validateProfileUpdate', 10, 3 );
add_filter('registration_errors', 'validateRegistration', 10, 3 );
add_action('validate_password_reset', 'validatePasswordReset', 10, 2 );

function validateProfileUpdate( WP_Error &$errors, $update, &$user ) {
    return validateComplexPassword( $errors );
}

function validateRegistration( WP_Error &$errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    return validateComplexPassword( $errors );
}

function validatePasswordReset( WP_Error &$errors, $userData ) {
    return validateComplexPassword( $errors );
}

function validateComplexPassword( $errors ) {

    $password = ( isset( $_POST[ 'pass1' ] ) && trim( $_POST[ 'pass1' ] ) ) ? $_POST[ 'pass1' ] : null;

    if ( empty( $password ) || ( $errors->get_error_data( 'pass' ) ) )
        return $errors;

    $passwordValidation = validatePassword($password);

    if ( $passwordValidation !== true ) {
        $errors->add( "pass", "<strong>ERROR</strong>: " . $passwordValidation . "." );
    }

    return $errors;
}

function validatePassword($Password) {
    
    //#### Check it's greater than 6 Characters
    if (strlen($Password) < 6) {
        return "Password is too short (" . strlen($Password) . "), please use 6 characters or more.";
    }

    //#### Test password has uppercase and lowercase letters
    if (preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).+$/", $Password) !== 1) {
        return "Password does not contain a mix of uppercase & lowercase characters.";
    }

    //#### Test password has mix of letters and numbers
    if (preg_match("/^((?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z]))(?=.*\d).+$/", $Password) !== 1) {
        return "Password does not contain a mix of letters and numbers.";
    }

    //#### Password looks good
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude certain roles like this:

1- Create a function to check if the current user role is excluded:

```
function isPasswordValidationSkipped()
{
    // Fill this array with roles that you want to exclude from password validation
    $excludedRoles = ['subscriber'];

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        if(in_array($role, $excludedRoles)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

2- Then use that function inside "validateComplexPassword" Like this:

```
function validateComplexPassword( $errors ) {

    $password = ( isset( $_POST[ 'pass1' ] ) && trim( $_POST[ 'pass1' ] ) ) ? $_POST[ 'pass1' ] : null;

    if ( true === isPasswordValidationSkipped() || empty( $password ) || ( $errors->get_error_data( 'pass' ) ) )
        return $errors;

    $passwordValidation = validatePassword($password);

    if ( $passwordValidation !== true ) {
        $errors->add( "pass", "<strong>ERROR</strong>: " . $passwordValidation . "." );
    }

    return $errors;
}
```